# Google Maps API 3 - Buscar endereço por CEP + número (geocode)

Tags: google-maps

Tenho feito em uma aplicação a exibição de pontos no mapa a partir de um endereço digitado em formulário. Utilizo a API v.3, javascript, e obtenho o endereço usando geocoder.geocode(x,y). Tenho seguido o seguinte formato: *tipo_logradouro logradouro, número - bairro - cidade, estado - país*. Funciona OK.

Mas para melhorar a procura, em casos onde o endereço não é encontrado, tentei fazer como alternativa buscar pelo cep (que já me daria a rua) mais o número, mas não estou conseguindo.

Para buscar pelo cep consigo fazer: *cep - país*. Assim ele encontra a rua correta, porém não consigo passar o número por exemplo da residência. Como isso poderia ser feito?

Comment: Teste isto:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=73050-140&sensor=false
-
Você deve enviar o CEP ou o endereço...

Comment: Realmente tem a necessidade de ser pelo google api?

Comment: Como faz para procurar pelo nome da rua e número? Qual a formatação que se envia na URL?

Answer (score -3):

Normalmente, quando existem formulários onde existem o campo de cep. todos os campos relacionados ao endereço são preenchidos, exceto o numero e complemento.